# Cannot assign "'10000'": "Jobs.client_id" must be a "Clients" instance

Tags: django, django-models

I have two tables, Jobs and Clients.

```
class Jobs(models.Model):
    client_id = models.ForeignKey(Clients,db_column='client_id',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Clients(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I have Jobs data in json format.

```
jobs_data = {
   'client_id':'10000',
   ....
}
```

When I want to save this data into Jobs table I get the `ValueError: Cannot assign "'10000'": "Jobs.client_id" must be a "Clients" instance.`

To save the table I have tried
`jobs_obj = Jobs.objects.create(**v['Job'])`

I also tried -

```
client_obj = Clients.objects.get(id=v['Job']['client_id'])
jobs_obj = Jobs.objects.create(**v['Job'],Clients=client_obj)
```

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Your Job model must be after Client model. You can't create Job model before of Clients model because you are referencing Job model to Clients model using  Foreign Key.

Comment: @ManojTolagekar   Lets say If I already have Clients Model and I want to update the Jobs table then How can I do that?

Comment: @Anonymous Do you have an existing row in your Clients table with an id of 10000?

Comment: @IainShelvington yes. I tried to do something like this `client_obj = Clients.objects.get(id=10000)` and then `jobs_obj = Jobs.objects.create(**v['Job'],Clients=client_obj)` but did not work.

Comment: @Anonymous you have to either pass the client object as the `client_id` keyword argument (`Jobs.objects.create(client_id=client_obj)`) or pass the id as `client_id_id` (`Jobs.objects.create(client_id_id=10000)`). ForeignKey are not usually named with the _id suffix because a descriptor with the suffix is automatically generated for the field and it is confusing